# MATLAB: ways to compute the settling time of a signal in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math

I would like to compute the settling time of a signal y in Matlab. It should give  the amount of time required before the signal reaches a steady state error |y(t)-y_{ss}| which is smaller than some absolute value x and stays smaller than x for all future times.

I already tried to use the Matlab function stepinfo, but this defines the value x as "a fraction 2% of their peak value for all future times" and that is not what i want.

Is there any way that i could adjust the Matlab function stepinfo, or a way that i could code this myself?

Comment: You might be able to achieve this by calculating the finite difference using `diff(signal)` and then determine when the result does not change more than a certain threshold.

Comment: Thank you, i already found a way to do it in the meantime. this is the code for anyone interested:  St = tspan(find(error>x, 1, 'last' )); where error = abs(y-y_ss)